# Shiny renderPlot within Interactive Document opens a new Browser Window with dygraph

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dygraphs

I have the following `RMarkdown .Rmd` document.  When you run the following, the `sliderInput` is "reactive" and adjust the smoothing appropriately; however, the plot keeps generating in a new separate browser window rather than within the document itself.

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix this behavior?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(dygraphs)
sliderInput("span", label = "Select Span",
            min=0.05, max=1, value=0.5, step=0.05)

renderPlot({
  plx <- predict(loess(ldeaths ~ time(ldeaths), span=input$span), se =T)
  fit <- plx$fit
  lower <- plx$fit - qt(0.975, plx$df) * plx$se
  upper <- plx$fit + qt(0.975, plx$df) * plx$se
  all <- cbind(ldeaths, fit, lower, upper)

  dygraph(all, main="Title") %>%
    dySeries(c("lower", "fit", "upper"), label="Deaths")
})
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm an idiot, the answer is that there's already a `renderDygraph()` function within the `dygraphs` package!

I'm going to keep this open so maybe someone can explain to me what's going on behind the scenes that makes this work correctly and why you cannot use `renderPlot()` directly.  I will try and remember to update this answer if I learn from looking through the source.

Comment: There was a nice overview webinar of `htmlwidgets` provided by RStudio that was helpful that hints at why you need a `render` method per each type of widget.

Comment: any suggestions wich render function to use when I am plotting with ggvis? I actually watched the webinar, but I dont recall any special rendering function they were using...